# How to make a React Hook dependent on another?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and working with React Hooks. I want to have react hooks for the user inputs and another array ( here the last chunk of the code) which automatically updates when User Input gets changed. I tried following but I think I'm on the wrong line. Does somebody know how I could manage this?

```
// User Inputs

const [hurdleRatesBC, sethurdleRatesBC] = useState({
  bcLombard: initialValue.bcLombard
});

const [maturitiesMarkups1, setmaturitiesMarkups1] = useState({
  onSightMarkup: initialValue.onSightMarkup
});

const [ratingMarkups, setratingMarkups] = useState({
  ratingAMarkup: initialValue.ratingAMarkup
});

// Destructuring

const { bcLombard: bcl } = hurdleRatesBC;

const {
  ratingAMarkup: ra,
  ratingBMarkup: rb,
  ratingCMarkup: rc
} = ratingMarkups;

const {
  onSightMarkup: m11,
  lt1mMarkup: m12,
  oneTo12mMarkup: m13,
  oneTo5yMarkup: m14,
  gt5yMarkup: m15
} = maturitiesMarkups1;

// Should be updated automatically  when changing Userinput

const [totalInputRates, settotalInputRates] = useState([
  {
    name: "On Sight",
    product: "bcl",
    "Rating C": roundSum(bcl, m11, rc),
    "Rating B": roundSum(bcl, m11, rb),
    "Rating A": roundSum(bcl, m11, ra)
  }
]);
```

Comment: You are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y (your solution).

Comment: What is your problem X?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, initialize the state which you want to update, which in your case seems to be `const [totalInputRates, setTotalInputRates] = useState([])`

Then you can use the useEffect hook, like so

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTotalInputRates(your values)
}, [hurdleRatesBC, maturitiesMarkups1, ratingMarkups])
```

The dependency array is where you put the state. If these variables change, useEffect hook is triggered and so your `setTotalInputRates` is too.

[You can read more about the useEffect here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works only for "lazy patterns", when the second hook is returning a function that can be called at will. This won't work for non-lazy hooks, like Apollo `useQuery`. 
In this case, you can either use the lazy version (exactly like you've shown), but also use the `skip` option of the `useQuery`: more generic answer would be that the second hook should be able to take care of his own input internally (should it wait for a value to be defined to trigger a side-effect for instance)